# How to check the time taken by a chunk of code in R

Tags: r, profiling

I want to check the time taken by a piece of code. Is there any way to do this.I would like  to know all the times like `(user, system, and elapsed)` time taken for a small portion of my code.
say my code have different segments

`code 1......
...........
...........`

`code2.........
...............
...............`

so i want the time taken by `code 1` . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start the clock at your desired location by:

`ptm <- proc.time()` ## start of clock and then to end

`proc.time()-ptm`  ## end of clock.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way:

```
system.time({ code chunk })
```

Answer (score 6):

That analysis is called 'profiling' and [described here in the Writing R Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Tidying-and-profiling-R-code) as well as in [Hadley's adv-R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) book.  My website also has a few (older) presentations covering this as part of introductions to High-Performance Computing, and the [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) lists tools in the area.